# Add custom block in checkout page, payment metod

Tags: checkout, magento-1

I want to add some block or widget in the Checkout page, as the following, to can custom the additional blocks:
[image]

the photo is from other website,
I'm waiting some advice
Thank you,

Comment: Try this http://inchoo.net/magento/adding-a-new-tab-under-one-page-checkout-full-working-module/

Comment: Thank you, but i don't want to install other extention. But there should be alternative way to add this block.